# How can I select rows from table A whose id matches those from table B, but whose (non id) values are different?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider these two data.tables, `foo` and `bar`.

```
foo <- data.table(id = c(1,2,3,4), f1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), f2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
bar <- data.table(id = c(1,2,3,4), f1 = c("a", "a", "c", "d"), f2 = c("a", "b", "c", "e"))

foo
   id f1 f2
1:  1  a  a
2:  2  b  b
3:  3  c  c
4:  4  d  d

bar
   id f1 f2
1:  1  a  a
2:  2  a  b
3:  3  c  c
4:  4  d  e
```

**I know that `foo` and `bar` have a 1-1 relationship.**

I would like to select rows from `bar` such that the corresponding row in `foo` has different values. For example,

- id 1: the values of `f1` and `f2` are the same in `foo` and bar, so exclude this one
- id 2: the value of `f1` has changed! include this in the result
- id 3: the values of `f1` and `f2` are the same in `foo` and bar, so exclude this one
- id 4: the value of `f2` has changed! include this in the result

### Expected Result

```
bar[c(2,4)]
   id f1 f2
1:  2  a  b
2:  4  d  e
```

### What I tried

I thought a non-equi join would work great here.. Unfortunately, it seems the "not equals" operator isn't supported.?

```
foo[!bar, on = c("id=id", "f1!=f1", "f2!=f2")]
# Invalid operators !=,!=. Only allowed operators are ==<=<>=>.

foo[!bar, on = c("id=id", "f1<>f1", "f2<>f2")]
# Found more than one operator in one 'on' statement: f1<>f1. Please specify a single operator.
```

Comment: are you looking for data.table solution only?

Comment: @Maël, I strongly prefer data.table because I need the speed, but alternatives are always welcome.

Comment: I think you're looking for an anti_join, so in dplyr it'd be `anti_join(bar, foo)`.

Comment: @Maël, I'm not looking for an anti join. This is distinctly different. (Re-read my question and / or try my toy example and you'll see why.)

Comment: @akrun thanks, that error message could use some spaces :)  ..but also darn, that's too bad.

Comment: Hopefully there's a better solution, but worst case you could do one join with `<`, one with `>` and combine the results.

Comment: Hrmm, perhaps an anti-join is the way to go (as @Maël suggested) since I know there's a 1-1 mapping between `foo` and `bar`. I guess I need to think about how that affects performance and if there's a better way.

Comment: Then what about the data.table version `fsetdiff(bar, foo, all = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Closest existing github issue I could fine is [this one](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1068). Not sure how related it is. If not closely related, this would make a good feature request.

Answer (score 3):

With `data.table`:

```
bar[foo,.SD[i.f1!=x.f1|i.f2!=x.f2],on="id"]

      id     f1     f2
   <num> <char> <char>
1:     2      a      b
2:     4      d      e
```

Answer (score 2):

Benchmarking on a larger dataset with a few different `data.table` options. The `mapply` option works only if `all.equal(foo$id, bar$id)` (depends on exactly what is meant by "1-1 relationship").

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)

foo <- data.table(id = 1:1e5, f1 = 1:1e5, f2 = 1:1e5)
mix <- sample(1e5, 5e4)
bar <- copy(foo)[mix[1:25e3], f1 := 0L][mix[25001:5e4], f2 := 0L]

head(fsetdiff(bar, foo))
#>    id f1 f2
#> 1:  5  0  5
#> 2:  6  6  0
#> 3:  7  0  7
#> 4:  8  0  8
#> 5: 10  0 10
#> 6: 12 12  0

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(join = bar[foo,.SD[i.f1!=x.f1|i.f2!=x.f2],on="id"],
                               antijoin = bar[!foo, on=.(id,f1,f2)],
                               fsetdiff = fsetdiff(bar, foo),
                               duplicated = bar[(!duplicated(rbindlist(list(bar, foo)), fromLast = TRUE))[1:nrow(bar)]],
                               mapply = bar[rowSums(mapply(function(i) foo[[i]] != bar[[i]], 2:length(bar))) > 0,],
                               check = "equal")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>        expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>        join 12.2306 14.07125 15.133795 14.76330 15.96645 22.4534   100
#>    antijoin 16.2002 17.60420 19.234747 18.30230 19.44395 59.1581   100
#>    fsetdiff 20.1408 21.76150 23.080961 23.03760 23.73860 30.9594   100
#>  duplicated 17.8954 20.12690 21.673165 21.66795 22.79185 27.3250   100
#>      mapply  3.2440  3.56480  4.346703  3.87415  4.63610 10.2100   100
```

Comment: I ran the benchmark but all result in empty tables and ran in no time (don't think they ran at all). Something went wrong?

Comment: Yep. `foo` was being modified when creating `bar` (so they were both pointing to the same object, according to `tracemem`). I've updated the answer. Thanks for the heads-up, @SweepyDodo.

Comment: np. Was exciting to see performance of `mapply`. Not only does it require a 1-1 relationship (tho this was confirmed by OP), it also requires both `df` to be sorted. Not saying this is a big disadvantage. Just had to point out.
Thanks for the benchmark!

Comment: Sorted is too strong of a requirement--the `mapply` solution requires only that `all.equal(foo$id, bar$id)` returns `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is best (cleanest, but perhaps not fastest?):

```
bar[!foo, on=.(id,f1,f2)]

      id     f1     f2
   <num> <char> <char>
1:     2      a      b
2:     4      d      e
```

Answer (score 1):

As other than `data.table` solution are also welcomed. Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

left_join(foo, bar, by="id") %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(identical = n_distinct(unlist(cur_data())) == 1) %>% 
  filter(identical == FALSE) %>% 
  select(id, f1=f1.y, f2=f2.y)
```

```
 Groups:   id [2]
     id f1    f2   
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     2 a     b    
2     4 d     e
```